# Login with facebook works on real phones but not emulators, it started happening with the new emulator update

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

This code works on real phones but not on emulators
I use flutter_facebook_auth. This exact code worked fine before emulator update and it's still works on real devices, but on emulator it just do nothing after coming back from fb login page.

```
static Future<User?> signInWithFacebook() async {
  try {
    //Trigger the sign-in flow
    final LoginResult loginResult =
        await FacebookAuth.instance.login(permissions: [
      'public_profile',
      'email',
      'user_friends',
    ]);
    if (loginResult.status == LoginStatus.success) {
      print('success');
      facebookAuthCredential =
          FacebookAuthProvider.credential(loginResult.accessToken!.token);
      print(loginResult.accessToken?.token);
      Credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
      print('here 1');
      UserData = await FacebookAuth.instance.getUserData(
          fields:
              "name,email,picture.width(400),birthday,friends,gender,link");
      print(UserData);
    } else {
      print(loginResult.message);
      error = loginResult.message!;
    }
    user = Credential.user;
    await user
        ?.updatePhotoURL(UserData['picture']['data']['url'])
        .then((value) {
      print('success' + UserData['picture']['data']['url']);
    });
    return Credential.user;
  } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
    error = e.code;
    print(e.code);
  }
}
}
```

In the above code the app flow stops or freezes on
`Credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);`

What I have tried is:

- Tried other emulators, different api's and models.
- I tried adding new release and debug keyhashes to both facebook and firebase
- I tried increasing emulator ram and cpu cores etc
- I tried refreshing fb sdk and json and other dev dependencies
- I tried flutter clean
- I tried Invalidate Caches
- I uninstalled android studio and all of it's components and install again

Is this happening with just me or it's a bug in the new emulator update?
It's been 12 hours, can somebody please help and check if their updated emulator is working with fb login

Comment: If you have a problem with the emulator and you're certain it's new in a certain version, you should post an issue on GitHub with your debugging details. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by downgrading emulator version to `31.2.9`,
Here is [emulator_archive](https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive) how you can do it: